# Create list view with unlimited items

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, web-part, external-content-type, external-list

We have a requirement in SharePoint Online to create list view that can view more than 100,000 items. We have a custom list synchronization with email, and there are more than 16,000 item creates every day at this list.

I know that the maximum list view limit is 5000 items, but I want to know if there is any way or third party to allowed to view all items of current month in one view?

What if I use external data base of another website and access by API services? I want to know how can I access with this external database and execute commands like insert items to external DB, updates, query by workflow when items are created?

Can I do it By HTTP action that is in SP Designer 2013?

Answer (score 4):

Not recommended to do in SharePoint, the actual working cap is 5000 items in a list or library in SharePoint Online even though the architectural limit is 30 million. You lose almost all ability to do anything in the list administratively. There are several user voice requests on this topic and I have personally submitted Premier requests. There is nothing you or they can do once you go over 5000 items. People can continually dump stuff in, but it becomes near impossible to manage.

The best you will be able to do is read items through the REST API in batches, it gives you a next url to call to get the next load of data. You'll need to use REST API to do other CRUD operations, that are not necessarily guaranteed to work.

Do it in an external db, and surface it in SharePoint Online however you wish.

Comment: I made api with external DB to query from by workflow call http action , 
but the request give me this result as xml 
`<name>Mahmoud</name>
<lastname>amin</lastname>
<born>1981</born>`
i get error when i try to get result by workflow , i think it's because the format of result in xml must convert to json
thank you Mr.Eric Alexander

Comment: can i get the parameters like lastname and born by in REST API query , 
and How can i insert into Table of external DB by workflow ?

Comment: Those are questions for a separate post